# Confused in Type.GetType

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I was reading C# in depth and I couldn't understand the para of the chapter

> Another method—this time one that already existed in .NET 1.1—that’s
>   worth exploring is `Type.GetType(string)`, and its related
>   `Assembly.GetType(string)` method, both of which provide a dynamic
>   equivalent to `typeof`. You might expect to be able to feed each line of
>   the output of listing 3.11 to the `GetType` method called on an
>   appropriate assembly, **but unfortunately life isn’t quite that
>   straightforward. It’s fine for closed constructed types—the type
>   arguments just go in square brackets. For generic type definitions,
>   though, you need to remove the square brackets entirely— otherwise
>   `GetType` thinks you mean an array type. Listing 3.12 shows all of these
>   methods in action.**

and in the example code author did what he asked not to do I believe :

```
string listTypeName = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1";
Type defByName = Type.GetType(listTypeName);

Type closedByName = Type.GetType(listTypeName + "[System.String]"); // did here ? , since he passed the listTypeName + [Type args] , so compiler should think it's array?
Type closedByMethod = defByName.MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
```

or might I got the things wrong , can anyone please elaborate with examples what he meant by line **"For generic type definitions, though, you need to remove the square brackets entirely— otherwise `GetType` thinks you mean an array type"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` is the name of the closed generic type.

And the name of the open generic type is not `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[] `` but `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``.

That's basically all that this paragraph says.

Comment: @HolyKiller: No need for that feeling :-)

Answer (score 1):

.Net type names passed by string use `[<type1>(,<typeN>)]` to indicate a generic type/function parameter list.  `[]` on it's own indicates an array type.

Also, any generic type name will have the construct:

```
`n
```

After its string name to indicate the *number* of generic parameters that the type has.  So:

```
MyNamespace.MyType`1
```

References the *open generic type* `MyNamespace.MyType<>` (i.e. with no generic arguments supplied).

Whereas

```
MyNamespace.MyType`1[System.String]
```

References the *closed generic type* `MyNamespace.MyType<string>`.

Note that there are further rules to do with `Type.GetType` - that being that you can only omit the assembly name (including public key token if applicable) when either:

1. The type requested can be found in the calling assembly
2. The type request is in `mscorlib`.

So, many core types can be specified by string with just their namespace-qualified name, including the generics - and the same goes for when a type name is specified as a type argument (as with `System.String` above).